# Autoloading new rating/start system data in a site when getting to bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a call to an autoload function in my index.php file to load more data when reach the bottom of the page. I also define here the style for my rating (stars):

```
<style>
span.stars, span.stars span {
display: block;
background: url(stars.png) 0 -16px repeat-x;
width: 80px;
height: 16px;
}
span.stars span {
background-position: 0 0;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var track_load = 0; //total loaded record group(s)
    var cityname = '<?=$city;?>';
var loading  = false; //to prevents multipal ajax loads
var total_groups = <?=$total_groups;?>; //total record group(s)
    var total_rows = <?=$get_total_rows;?>;

$('#results').load("autoload_process.php",     {'group_no':track_load,'nameofcity':cityname}, function() {track_load++;}); //load first group
$(window).scroll(function() { //detect page scroll

    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())  //user scrolled to bottom of the page?
    {
        if(track_load <= total_groups && loading==false) //there's more data to load
        {
            loading = true; //prevent further ajax loading
            $('.animation_image').show(); //show loading image
            //load data from the server using a HTTP POST request
            $.post('autoload_process.php',{'group_no': track_load, 'nameofcity':cityname}, function(data){
                $("#results").append(data); //append received data into the element
                //hide loading image
                $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received
                track_load++; //loaded group increment
                loading = false; 
            }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?
                alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error
                $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image
                loading = false;
            });
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Then in my autoload_process.php I retrieve info from my data base and I print it. One of the info I retrieve and print is the rating. I also have in this file my script to print the rating.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('span.stars').stars();
});

$.fn.stars = function() {
return $(this).each(function() {
$(this).html($('<span />').width(Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, parseFloat($(this).html())))) * 16));
});
}
</script>

    $db = pg_connect("$db_host $db_name $db_username $db_password");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table;
    $rating = $myrow[rating];
    echo '<span class="stars">'; 
    echo $rating;
    echo '</span>';
```

When the page is load for the first time everything works fine but the problem I have is that when I scroll all the way to the bottom and the page is reload with the new info the rating changes. It seams that everytime that a new set of data is loaded all the previous ratings are set to the value of the first item of all (Hotel 1 as per example)

**Example:** (let's say that I load 3 results at a time)

**First Load:**

```
Hotel 1 -->  Rating 5  (This is correct)    
Hotel 2 -->  Rating 4  (This is correct)    
Hotel 3 -->  Rating 3  (This is correct)
```

Now I get to the bottom of the page and the next info is loaded (**second load**):

```
Hotel 1 -->  Rating 5  (This is INCORRECT) filled with first value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 2 -->  Rating 5  (This is INCORRECT) filled with first value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 3 -->  Rating 5  (This is INCORRECT) filled with first value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 4 -->  Rating 2  (This is correct)    
Hotel 5 -->  Rating 1  (This is correct)    
Hotel 6 -->  Rating 3  (This is correct)
```

Now I get to the bottom of the page and the next info is loaded (**third load**):

```
Hotel 1 -->  Rating 5  (This is INCORRECT) filled with first value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 2 -->  Rating 5  (This is INCORRECT) filled with first value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 3 -->  Rating 5  (This is INCORRECT) filled with first value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 4 -->  Rating 5  (This is INCORRECT) filled with first value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 5 -->  Rating 5  (This is INCORRECT) filled with first value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 6 -->  Rating 5  (This is INCORRECT) filled with first value (Hotel1)    
Hotel 7 -->  Rating 3  (This is correct)    
Hotel 8 -->  Rating 2  (This is correct)    
Hotel 9 -->  Rating 1  (This is correct)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In your autoload script the `$query` seems to be partially missing? There's no `LIMIT` or `OFFSET`. For the offset might want to use the `group_no` (very odd name, did you ever hear of naming conventions?) that you request the data with.

A side-note, when you request data from the server you should use a GET request, only when you send data to the server you use POST. `$.load` does set a GET request but it's the `$.post` a few lines down that's wrong.

Comment: Thank you Thomas for your response. I just put that query as an example  in my code I have "ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT $items_per_group OFFSET $position"" . The issue is related with the <script> in the autoload_process.php file. Something is not working correctly when I scroll all the way to the bottom and the page is reload with the new info the rating changes. That's the issue I'm trying to solve but cannot figure out. Thank you again for your reply

Comment: And again your naming is all over the place with `$position`. Please use only one variable name for one thing.

I'd recommend starting from scratch, put the js code to load content into a function and use only that to a) load the first three (thus you can remove that `$.load()` and b) load every other page (thus scrapping the `$.post` which should be a `$.get`).

Refactoring will allow you to writer cleaner code and pinpoint you problem much easier.